# How to build specific app APK with Android Studio when the project contains multiple apps?

Tags: android, build, structure, project

I try to build and run the sample `helloworld/mobile` in project (https://github.com/android/car-samples)

My question is about how to select the sample app directory as described in README.md:

> > > > 

2. Select a sample app directory (e.g. `helloworld/mobile`) in the `Project Structure` UI on the top left. Each sample app has two build targets, one for the `mobile` platform and the other for the `automotive` platform.
   <<<<

I went through `Project Structure` UI, I tried different possibilities but no way,
Build menu always shows **Make Module `car-simples-main`** and when I launch Make Module, nothing happens.

Wondering if something has changed in the last Android Studio version,
I use Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's understand how the git directory is structured.

The directory has the two folders `car-lib/CarGearViewerKotlin` and `car_app_library`, which are gradle projects that can be built using gradle.

How do you know?
Any folder contains `gradle wrapper` and a `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files means that they're ready to be built using gradle, and these can contain modules inside of them.

Now `helloworld/mobile` is a module, or you can view it as a sub-project.

How do you know?
If you open up the parent's `settings.gradle` file, you will see the line `include ':helloworld:mobile'` meaning that the directory `helloworld/mobile` is a sub-project or module for the top level `car_app_library` project.
Modules by themselves are not runnable, they need to be contained in a parent project with top-level gradle files.

Now the solution for your problem should be: open up these two as projects in Android studio individually: `car-lib/CarGearViewerKotlin` and `car_app_library`, it will create a default run configuration for each project.
You won't be able to run `helloworld/mobile` alone, you'll need to run the parent project `car-samples/car_app_library`.

However, You should technically be able to open the root directory (the git directory containing all of the projects) and creating a run configurations by hand for each project, and you should be able to run the projects using one Android Studio window opened.